# Get dictionary key from attributes of a class in the value python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, dictionary

I have a user class for my server:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, username, password, group, join_date):
        self.password = password
        self.group = group
        self.join_date = join_date
```

I also have a dictionary with user ID's as the keys. The format for adding a user would be:

```
users = {
    1443: User("Bob", "my_password", "admin", "June 23")
}
```

My problem is when users log in to their account:

```
username = input()
password = getpass.getpass()
```

I wanted to have something like:

```
if username in users:
    if users[username].password == password
```

I can't do this because I don't know how I can get the user ID from the username of the user since it is embedded in an object. Any ideas or recommendations? I am new to authentication/authorization.

Comment: Are you missing a `self.username = username` line in the `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options; either loop through all objects and find the user that matches the login name, or map from username to userid or directly to the user object.

Looping requires a linear search through all the values of your `users` dictionary:

```
for user in users:
    if user.username == username and user.password == password:
        # success!
```

You could generate a mapping from username to userid once, and then use that mapping:

```
usernames = {user.username: userid for userid, user in users.items()}
```

then use:

```
if username in usernames:
    userid = usernames[username]
    if users[userid].password == password
```

This is far faster than a linear search each time, the direct lookup in a mapping is a O(1) constant time lookup.

You could just make the mapping point to the user object directly:

```
usernames = {user.username: user for userid, user in users.items()}
```

If your program adds or removes users, you'll need to maintain this extra mapping too.

Comment: @banana: using the mapping is far faster.